# Balance of an non-homogeneous object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium, statics, stability

Would a pencil balanced on its tip, remain balanced if the the tip was made of a material twice as heavy than the rest of the pencil?

Answer (score 0):

If the there no torque, yes, the pencil is still balanced at the unstable equilibrium point. In the case the mass distribution should be radically symmetric. It is not important that the mass distribution varies along the length of the object.